# Symfony 2 generate translation files from DB

Tags: php, symfony, translation, yaml

I have database with strings and translations for them in few languages. I need to generate yaml files and then set them to work.

I have no idea how to start, what steps should I follow?

I saw JMSTranslationBundle, but I don't know if it can generate yaml files. I already created my own TranslatingBundle, so I'm not using this bundle to make translations in DB etc.

All I need is generate yaml files and set them to work in project.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what You need to do with this files is it one time generation or what.
But if You have translations in DB write Your own service for translations.
Your class should implement `TranslatorInterface`, you can look at `Translator` class how its done, all you need to change is the way to get your translations (DB query)

Comment: I need to generate yaml files with translations and then set this file as translation for project. For example, I have cz, sk, en languages in projekt and if you will go to sk.example.com it will have already generated yaml file with translations and just show you page in slovak language. Also I will be able import this file back to app, load this translations and string to database and edit them in my translating app.

Comment: So You want to with every change or adding new translation generate new yml files ?? Sounds awkward

Comment: No, only after clicking on generate.